# Sending an email through VB6

Tags: vb6, email

I am wondering if there is a way to send an email (SMTP) through VB6. I have an application that just needs to send a simple email when the user is done to let a group know that the application has processed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539242/sending-e-mail-via-smtp-using-vb6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155611/send-emails-through-vb6-if-no-email-client

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep - depends on which version of windows you're using. Assuming one of the later versions - CDO.Message works great.

```
Sub SendMessage(MailFrom,MailTo,Subject,Message)
    Dim ObjSendMail
    Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

    With ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields
    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smpt server Address"
    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

    ' If your server requires outgoing authentication uncomment the lines below and use a valid email address and password.
'    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
'    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = MailFrom
'    .Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = yourpassword

    .Update
    End With

    'End remote SMTP server configuration section==

    ObjSendMail.To = MailTo
    ObjSendMail.Subject = Subject
    ObjSendMail.From = MailFrom

    ' we are sending a html email.. simply switch the comments around to send a text email instead
    ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = Message
    'ObjSendMail.TextBody = Message

    ObjSendMail.Send

    Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: By setting a reference to the library you also get named constants for those field names and magic numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You should hopefully have the CDOSYS libraries installed on your machine:

> [CDO Messaging - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa488400%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)
>   [Creating and Sending a Message - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526497%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx)
>   [Sending email using CDOSYS ( THE REAL DEAL )](http://www.powerasp.com/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp)
>   [ASP Sending e-mail with CDOSYS](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)

If you don't have that library (and aren't able to install it) then there's always CDONTS to fall back on but it is deprecated:

> [Using the CDONTS component to send email from ASP pages.](http://www.powerasp.com/content/hintstips/asp-email.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I found this [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=232562):

```
Dim UserName$, UserMail$, MailRecipiant$, MailBody$, SockData$

Private Sub Command1_Click()
UserName = "YourUserName_or_Addr"
UserMail = "Your Name <You@provider.com>"
MailRecipiant = UserMail
MailBody = "The message goes here"
Winsock1.LocalPort = 0
Winsock1.RemoteHost = "smtp-server"
Winsock1.RemotePort = 25
Winsock1.Connect
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
Label1 = "Sending message..."
Winsock1.SendData "EHLO " & UserName & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("250") Then GoTo 100
Winsock1.SendData "MAIL FROM: " & UserMail & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("250") Then GoTo 100
Winsock1.SendData "RCPT TO: " & MailRecipiant & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("250") Then GoTo 100
Winsock1.SendData "DATA" & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("354") Then GoTo 100
Winsock1.SendData MailBody & vbCrLf & "." & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("250") Then GoTo 100
Winsock1.SendData "QUIT" & vbCrLf
If Not WaitFor("221") Then GoTo 100
Label1 = "Message sent"
GoTo 200
100
Label1 = SockData
200
Winsock1.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Winsock1.GetData SockData
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Error(ByVal Number As Integer, Description As String, ByVal Scode As Long, ByVal Source As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, ByVal HelpContext As Long, CancelDisplay As Boolean)
Label1 = "Error: " & Description
SockData = "Error"
Winsock1.Close
End Sub

Private Function WaitFor(SockResponse As String) As Boolean
Do While Left(SockData, 3) <> SockResponse And Left(SockData, 3) <> "220" And Left(SockData, 3) <> "250"
  DoEvents
  If Left(SockData, 3) > "400" Then Exit Function
Loop
WaitFor = 1
SockData = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps because this approach fails if you need encrypted authentication or SSL/TLS transmission?  Those are fairly common requirements anymore.  Attachments and HTML mail also add more clunkiness to this roll-your-own approach.  It's great in limited cases though.

Comment: "simple email when the user is done to let a group know that the application has processed"

Answer (score 0):

Dave has a good solution if you really need to send email from the client's PC.  However, sometimes you get into trouble with firewalls and such.  In the case where you are connecting to a SQL Server, I have found it is simpler and easier to manage if you proxy your mail through SQL Server (either by queuing it into an outgoing mail table, or calling the `xp_sendmail` stored proc itself).

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-up-sql-mail-to-send-sql-server-alerts/5094201) on how to get SQL Mail setup and working on the server, and at the end it shows how to use a stored procedure to send an email.

I found this solution to be advantageous because:

- Windows 7 computers were blocking all outbound SMTP
- Implementing all the retries and such to do outbound email "right" was quite complicated
- Using the queue method with SQL Server, but not actually setting up SQL Mail on my development or test databases, the emails stayed in the queue unless I was running against the production server